# compare timestamps in javascript

Tags: javascript, timestamp

I have a date saved in a string with this format: `2017-09-28T22:59:02.448804522Z` this value is provided by a backend service.

Now, in javascript how can I compare if that timestamp is greater than the current timestamp? I mean, I need to know if that time happened or not yet taking in count the hours and minutes, not only the date.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

That looks like a ISO8601 date string. You can parse it with `Date`'s constructor and use the built-in comparison operators.

```
new Date('2017-09-28T22:59:02.448804522Z') > new Date()
// true
new Date('2017-09-28T22:59:02.448804522Z') < new Date()
// false
```

Answer (score 13):

You could also convert it to unix time in milliseconds:

```js
console.log(new Date('2017-09-28T22:59:02.448804522Z').valueOf())

const currentTime = new Date('2017-09-28T22:59:02.448804522Z').valueOf()
    
const expiryTime = new Date('2017-09-29T22:59:02.448804522Z').valueOf()

if (currentTime < expiryTime) {
    console.log('not expired')
}
```

Comment: I did not know that the Date object would accept that format. Good to know.

Comment: You're parsing a easy readable ISO timestamp format to a non-human readable amount of numbers. If I was choose, I will clearly skip this answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
const anyTime = new Date("2017-09-28T22:59:02.448804522Z").getTime();
const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
if(currentTime > anyTime){
    //codes
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can, I would use moment.js
* https://momentjs.com/

You can create a moment, specifying the exact format of your string, such as:

```
var saveDate = moment("2010-01-01T05:06:07", moment.ISO_8601);
```

Then, if you want to know if the `saveDate` is in the past:

boolean isPast = (now.diff(saveDate) > 0);

If you can't include an external library, you will have to string parse out the year, day, month, hours, etc - then do the math manually to convert to milliseconds. Then using Date object, you can get the milliseconds:

```
var d = new Date();
var currentMilliseconds = d.getMilliseconds();
```

At that point you can compare your milliseconds to the currentMilliseconds. If currenMilliseconds is greater, then the saveDate was in the past.