# check current timestamp present between two timestamp

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a sending two timestamp start timestamp and end timestamp I have to check if the current timestamp in between the start and end timestamp then I have to change the variable value to true otherwise false.

```
{
    "start_time":"2020-04-23T06:49:55.510Z",
    "end_time":"2020-04-23T20:49:55.510Z",
    "form_type":"5e54b4e4d76bf807091043ae", 
    "book_id":"5e56469d42f0c5647625fd45",
}
```

i am sending the data in this from in mongodb

sudo code something like this

```
var check = false
currentTime = Date.now()
if(currentTime < Start_time  && currentTime < end_time)
{
   check = true
}
```

I am not able to make a query for this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [compare timestamps in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46478974/compare-timestamps-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

```
currentTime = new Date();
db.model.find({"start_time" : { $gte : new 
  ISODate(currentTime.toISOString()) },
"end_time" : { $lte : new 
  ISODate(currentTime.toISOString()) }
});
```

Can you please try this Mongo query and check whether it is working or not? Please change the code according to your need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use moment.js for that.

moment().utc();

This returns the current timestamp.

Then You need to convert your timestamp into a moment object.

```
compare_time = moment.utc('2020-04-21T06:49:55.510Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss[Z]');
```

After doing that compare that to the current time using "isAfter()". Here is a working example

```
var current = moment.utc();
var compare_time = moment.utc('2020-04-21T06:49:55.510Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss[Z]');
current.isAfter(compare_time); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare Date objects like so

```
var obj={
    "start_time":"2020-04-23T06:49:55.510Z",
    "end_time":"2020-04-23T20:49:55.510Z",
    "form_type":"5e54b4e4d76bf807091043ae", 
    "book_id":"5e56469d42f0c5647625fd45",
} 
var check=Date.parse(obj.start_time)<Date.now() && Date.now()<Date.parse(obj.end_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

A fairly simple comparison to do using `.getTime()` on the `Date` object.

```js
const jsonObject = {
  "start_time": "2020-04-23T06:49:55.510Z",
  "end_time": "2020-04-23T20:49:55.510Z",
  "form_type": "5e54b4e4d76bf807091043ae",
  "book_id": "5e56469d42f0c5647625fd45",
}

const startTime = new Date(jsonObject.start_time).getTime();
const endTime = new Date(jsonObject.end_time).getTime();
const currentTime = new Date().getTime();

console.log(startTime, currentTime, endTime);
console.log(startTime <= currentTime && currentTime <= endTime);
```

Comment: @lakshitsingh Pleasure, and if one of the answers solved your issue, resolve the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mongodb-aggregation.
Your query would be like:

```
currentTime = new Date()
db.model.aggregate([
{
    $set: {
        value: {
            $cond: [{currentTime: {$gt: "$start_time", $lt: "$end_time"}}, true, false]
        }
    }
}
])
```